# Errors when running the program in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++

I have these problems coming up, when trying to run the program in Visual Studio 2013 C++. I know the code is ok, but every time, this happens.

Error   1   error : The source file for this compilation can be found at:

> "C:\Users\Łukasz\AppData\Local\Temp\4fac5eed-ed73-4dda-8bdc-c333e2e82b4c.txt" C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets

Error   2

> error MSB3758: An error has occurred during compilation. error CS0016:
>   Could not write to output file
>   'c:\Users\Łukasz\AppData\Local\Temp\dtlusbnh.dll' -- 'Access is
>   denied. ' C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets

Error   3

> error MSB4036: The "SetEnvironmentVariable" task was not found. Check
>   the  following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the
>   same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and
>   implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task
>   is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the
>   *.tasks files located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin" directory. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets

Answer (score 2):

The

> **”** Could not write to output file

error message means that the file is in use.

Since it's a DLL, it's in use by some program or programs.

You need to terminate those processes.

Comment: It's not as simple as that. In my case an anti-virus software is preventing VS to write files to temporary files.

Comment: With an anti-virus program you can typically add exceptions for files and directories.

Comment: That is understood. Point is, to find out that anti-virus could be an issue  is not as straight forward as you said.

Answer (score 0):

> > Error 3
>
> error MSB4036: The "SetEnvironmentVariable" task was not found. Check
>   the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the
>   same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and
>   implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task
>   is correctly declared with in the project file, or in the *.tasks
>   files located in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin"
>   directory. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.targets

I had only the one error above, after repairing visual studio it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
Run Visual Studio as Administrator solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this issues for Visual Studio 2019 and running visual studio as administrator resolved the issue